# changing the width of a button dynamically by the change of label

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am working in a application which supports multiple language . I have a menu with some spark components like buttons . when I switch from one language to other the button width is not getting set according to the text of language . the sample codes follows .
thanks in adv.

```
     [Bindable]
        private var languageLabel:String;
private var mMenuLangData:LanguageData = LanguageData.getInstance();

        private function onLanguageChange(vEvent:Event):void
        {   
        languageLabel= mMenuLangData.menuLangData.getLabel(_index , MenuItemsLanguageData.MENU_ITEMS);
        }

        <s:Button id="btn" styleName="PrimaryToolItemButtonStyle" label="{languageLabel}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that code should work... What about the style you assigned? May be it sets the width of the component explicitly?

Comment: well, I did not specified the width explicitly in skin class .